# WITH is not working as I expected sqlServer 2012

Tags: sql-server, select, sql-server-2012, sql-delete, with-statement

I am getting diferents results into a WITH statement. here is my first query:

`with q as (select top (100000) * from table1) select * from q`

Let's say that table1 has an `ID` field, everything seems to be normal if I execute that query, it works as I expected. But if I change the statement like this:

`with q as (select top (100000) * from table1) select [ID] from q`
or
`with q as (select top (100000) * from table1) select q.[ID] from q`

it brings me results that does not exists into the first query (note that I only bring `ID`). I understand that WITH statement is a temporal result set an I expect that both queries brings the same result no matter how many fields I select, so why is this happening?, this could be a problem if i want to perform an update or even worst if I do a delete I will not be completely sure if I have affected the rows that I wanted

Comment: I understand your point and definitely that's the answer, now I am facing another problem an it is because the `order by` clause is doing the query slow, I really wanted to avoid it, thanks for the answer I'll mark as correct if you do it as answer.

Comment: If the ORDER BY makes the query slow, but that is how you get the order you want, why would you expect SQL Server to do that for you by default even if you don't specify? SQL Server's job is to get results to you in the most efficient way possible, and it's not going to read your mind and choose a slow method. If you want order by, you need to add ORDER BY to the query. If that makes it slow, then you can consider adding (or changing) an index to better support your desired ordering.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you `select top x` without an `order by`, the result set is arbitrarily returned. Meaning you can get a different result set if you execute it twice. Since you are changing the query slightly, I'm not surprised the result set is different. Add an `ORDER BY` if you `SELECT TOP x`